# How to get node data of nodes having the same node name using pugixml parsing?

Tags: c++, pugixml

I am getting the same node value for all the childen of a node which have the same child node name.For example here in my code I am getting the node data value of node name as ACHRA in all the cases.I want to get the correct node value .Please guide.

Here is my code:

XML code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' ?>

<student>
  <person>
    <name name="AttractMode0" >Achra</name>
    <name name="abc" >Elivia</name>
    <name name="def" >Christina</name>
    <gender name="AttractMode1" >female</gender>
    <country name="AttractMode2" >India</country>
  </person> 

  <person>
    <name name="AttractMode3" >georg</name>
    <gender name="AttractMode4" >male</gender>
    <country name="AttractMode5" >Austria</country>  
  </person>
</student>
```

---

C++ code

```
#include "pugixml-1.4/src/pugixml.cpp" 
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream> 
int main()
{
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    std::string namePerson;

    if (!doc.load_file("student.xml")) return -1;

    pugi::xml_node persons = doc.child("student");
    std::cout << persons.name() << std::endl;

for (pugi::xml_node person = persons.first_child(); person; person = person.next_sibling())
    {

        for (pugi::xml_attribute attr = person.first_attribute(); attr; attr = attr.next_attribute())
        {
            std::cout << " " << attr.name() << "=" << attr.value() << std::endl;
        }

        for (pugi::xml_node child = person.first_child(); child; child = child.next_sibling())
        {
            std::cout << child.name() <<"="<< person.child_value(child.name())<<std::endl;     // get element name
            // iterate through all attributes
            for (pugi::xml_attribute attr = child.first_attribute(); attr; attr = attr.next_attribute())
            {
                std::cout << " " << attr.name() << "=" << attr.value() << std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

---

My output is:

```
student

Person: 
name=Achra
 name=AttractMode0

name=Achra
 name=abc

name=Achra
 name=def

gender=female
 name=AttractMode1

country=India
 name=AttractMode2


Person: 
name=georg
 name=AttractMode3

gender=male
 name=AttractMode4

country=Austria
 name=AttractMode5
```

Comment: `#include "pugixml-1.4/src/pugixml.cpp"`: That looks just wrong!

Comment: @Dragosht: I am new to pugi ..so can you tell me the correct way ?? and also the way to find  a solution to my question?

Comment: I haven't used this pugixml library before. My remark was more of a good practice advice of not including cpp-s into other cpp-s. The quick start guide mentions this `#include "../libs/pugixml/src/pugixml.hpp"`. (http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing from your `pugixml` library documentation:

> > Plain character data nodes (node_pcdata) represent plain text in XML. PCDATA nodes have a value, but do not have name or children/attributes. Note that plain character data is not a part of the element node but instead has its own node; for example, an element node can have several child PCDATA nodes.

Just replace this line:

```
std::cout << child.name() << "=" << person.child_value(child.name()) << std::endl;
```

with something like this:

```
pugi::xml_node pcdata = child.first_child();
std::cout << child.name() << " = " << pcdata.value() << std::endl;
```

The output is now:

```
name = Achra
 name = AttractMode0
name = Elivia
 name = abc
name = Christina
 name = def
gender = female
 name = AttractMode1
country = India
 name = AttractMode2
name = georg
 name = AttractMode3
gender = male
 name = AttractMode4
country = Austria
 name = AttractMode5
```

You may also want to look at this [walker](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/samples/traverse_walker.cpp) - it seems way simpler.